# Generate a Game World using planet.osm in .pbf format

Tags: java, openstreetmap

I've recently downloading openstreetmap's Planet.osm for use in an experiment whereby I plan to generate a video game world based off of the planet. openstreetmap's wiki hasn't been very useful, and all I really want to perform is.

To start off, the simplest thing I want to do is:

- Create a text file, whereby each character corresponds to a point in planet.osm.pbf, with;

  - Water = 0;
  - Land = 1;

That's all I need to start.

Comment: crosspost: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120811/generate-a-game-world-using-planet-osm-in-pbf-format/120851#120851

Answer (score 0):

Using OSM for such a simple task seems like overkill. Take a look at the downloads provided by [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) instead.

If you really want to use OSM then you have to extract the [coastline](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Coastline) tagged with [natural=coastline](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dcoastline). You don't have to extract it yourself because there are already various sources offering pre-processed OSM data, for example [OpenStreetMap Data](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines)